# Tempermonkey hide class issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to hide a section from an html page:

```
<h1 data-ng-show="!menuPinned &amp;&amp; !isSaaS" class="logo floatLeft" aria-hidden="false"><span>XXX&nbsp;</span><span style="font-weight: bold;">XXX&nbsp;</span><span>XXXXX</span></h1>
```

I tried few things but nothing works:

```
var logo = document.querySelector('h1.logo.floatLeft');
logo.style.display = "none";
```

and

```
document.querySelector('h1.logo.floatLeft').remove();
```

Interesting enough, with the first option, if I add an id into my h1 (hardcoded with Chrome devtools) and I select but element Id, it works like a breeze.

With the second option, if I run the command in Chrome-console once, nothing happens, if I run twice, the h1 disappear.

I am using Tempermonkey, but I guess it's more a dom-js issue (in my code).

Any hint is very welcome.

Cheers, Giovanni

Comment: I suspect that there's more than one h1 tag with the "logo" and "floatLeft" classes (so by running the code twice, you are removing two h1s, but you are only seeing the removal of the second)

Comment: You should check how many matching elements by using the global method `length` first.

Comment: @jdb and super-cool handsome gel boy, you are definitely right, I found that there are 3 elements matching the query selector. 
I am now  facing another problem, no matter what.. I can't remove the section from the page, I tried many solutions (all without jquery) but it seems that the script always executed before the page is load (hence element not in the page yet).

Comment: @super-cool-handsome-gel-boy 
.
This is my last attempt, previously I tried window.onoad .. but nothing
.
    var ibmlogo = document.querySelectorAll('h1.logo.floatLeft');
    ibmlogo.onload = function() {removeLogo()};
    
    function removeLogo(){
        console.log("### ibmlogo array lenght: " + ibmlogo.length);
        ibmlogo[1].remove();

Comment: if you have a new question, please submit a new question. Don't ask new questions in the comments. They aren't useful to other programmers since they aren't indexed for search. But you may want to try searching for an answer first... that's usually the fastest way to get a solution.

Comment: @jdb, completely understand, if you answer the question (no comment) I can accept and vote for it, I guess this is the way for you to get more credits. Cheers.